# How to display a item of full size in div area?

Tags: html, css

I tried below code to display a 3D rectangle in a ionic application. The rectangle is cut and cannot be fully displayed. How to display this 3D rectangle fully in div.

```css
#prespective {
  padding-top:0%;
  width: 100px;
  height:100px;
  perspective: 300px;
  margin-right:auto;
  margin-left:auto;
}

#cube {
  transform: translateZ(0px)rotateX(0deg)rotateY(30deg);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition:.75s cubic-bezier(.22,.79,1,.31);
}

.face {
  background:#000;
  opacity:0.7;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:100px;
  font-size:2em;
  color:#fff;
  font-weight:900;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.faceFront  {
  transform: rotateY( 0deg) translateZ(50px);
}
.faceRight  { 
  transform: rotateY( 90deg) translateZ(50px);
}
.faceBack { 
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(50px); 
}
.faceLeft{ 
  transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(50px);
}
.faceTop{
  transform: rotateX( 90deg) translateZ(50px);
}
.faceBottom{
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(50px);
}
```

```html
<ion-card >
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>3D Rectangle</ion-label>
      </ion-item>

      <div id="prespective">
        <div id="cube">
            <div class="face faceFront">1</div>
        <div class="face faceBack"></div>
        <div class="face faceRight"></div>
        <div class="face faceLeft"></div>
        <div class="face faceTop"></div>
        <div class="face faceBottom"></div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </ion-list>
</ion-card>
```

[image]

Comment: Turned your code into snippet and it looks fine. Is there some other relevant part of your code that you didn't share here?

Comment: Thanks. It is part in my ionic android app. It shows the rectangle is cut on my phone. Can you please try it on your phone?